# Android Studio unable to merge github branches

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I have an Android app that is connected to github via Android studio.  I created a branch on Github when I wanted to add a new feature.  I have now completed the work on that branch so I tried to merge the branches when I ran into some issues.  I am very new to git/github.

In android studio I show Local Branches as master -> orgin/master, and then I have remote branches of

origin/interfacev2 (this was the branch I created)
origin/master
origin/master.lock

When I look at a compare, I can see all the changes on the interfacev2 branch that is not on the master, but when I click on merge it tells me it is already up to date.  I have tried going into the VCS->Git->Merge Changes as well, and there is not another branch for me to merge with (which is what the various tutorials I read said to do).

I then went into the github account itself to try and merge there.  I created a pull request on the interfacev2 branch, and it told me "This branch has conflicts that must be resolved", and apparently you cannot resolve the conflicts from the website (as far as I can tell).  It says you have to do it via command line or the desktop app.  I don't have anything hooked up to it via a command line, so I downloaded the desktop app.  With that I don't see how to merge either.  I tried to just open the command prompt from the app and run the commands suggested on the site, but all I get are a bunch of errors or it telling me it is already up to date (when I try to merge).

I am now at a complete loss. I have tried searching all day for an answer, but cannot find anything to my specific issue, at least not one that doesn't assume I am an expert at git. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you use ">git push -u origin YourBranch" when pushing your new branch ?

Comment: I push everything from Android Studio, which does not have a command line (as far as I know).  I set my branch as the interfacev2, then I hit the VCS commit button and commit and push from there.

Comment: Oh i see, i always work with git with the command shell.. Maybe you should give it a look. It's not hard to understand and you have full control of your project. [link](https://git-scm.com/doc)

Comment: You have **Terminal** tab at the bottom bar inside Andorid Studio. There you can run git commands